# Install IPython notebook on a remote server without root privileges

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I need to deploy [IPython Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Notebook) on an Ubuntu remote server.

One solution is to deploy it as a local user, without sudo privileges, on a system where other servers are already running.

The second solution is to setup a new server, and install IPython with sudo privileges.

I'd like to know before to start, if there are some requirements related to the IPython Notebook server deployment that can make solution 1 difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I found these tutorials particularly useful when setting up IPython nbserver:

- *[Create an iPython HTML Notebook on Amazon's AWS Free Tier from scratch](https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/5183133)*
- *[Running a notebook server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html)*

They don't require sudo privileges. You can also try setting up virtualenv to encapsulate the environment to the local user. However, it is necessary to set the port where Notebook can be accessed from the outside, so there can be potential conflict if you're not able to expose ports on the server.